# SFC Problem with the comment login

Tags: facebook

I want to use the comment function of the [SFC plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) for my [website](http://lbsfilm.tk/).

However, every time I click the log in with Facebook button a little window pops up asking for the app connection then disappears and nothing else happens.

I can use the comment form in the normal way but not with the Facebook log in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your theme has the proper wp_head() and wp_footer() function calls in it.